Azure CI Pipeline refer .Net Project Template and DB Project Template but some time .Net Project template only run and why DB template not run
There are multiple CI pipelines under a folder that refer to the same YAML file. This YAML file references two templates: one for a .NET project and another for a database project. CI pipelines for Dev1 through Dev9 have been created.
When running Dev1, only the .NET project template executes. However, some runs trigger both the .NET project template and the database project template.
Is there a reason why the database project template is not being executed in certain runs? Could it be because there are no changes in the database project?
The CI pipeline is triggered manually. Is there any caching that might be preventing the execution of the database template?
Please advise.
Thanks
